# How does the assignment of parameters to events work?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I was trying to create a automatic `role` assignment, if a `user` adds a specific `reaction` to a message I created.  While I was developing this I came across something I do not understand:

The [Discord.js docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) says, that the `messageReactionAdd event` supplies **two** `parameters`:

- `messageReaction`
- `user`

But my `event handler` binds only the `client` and `Discord` parameters to an event. Let me show you my code:

#### Event handler:

```js
module.exports = (client, Discord) => {
    const load_dir = (dirs) => {
        const event_flies = fs.readdirSync(`./events/${dirs}`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

        for(const file of event_flies) {

            const event = require(`../events/${dirs}/${file}`);

            const event_name = file.split('.')[0];

            client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, client, Discord));
        }
    };

    ['client', 'guild'].forEach(e => load_dir(e));
};
```

I created that `handler` with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sihf7B8D4Y8&t=947s) and I still don't understand why the first `parameter` is *null*...

#### MessageReactionAdd event:

```js
module.exports = (client, Discord, reaction) => {
    
    console.log('Test');
}
```

I debugged at the `console.log()` to check, if the parameters are correct.

Now there are two things I don't understand:

- Where does the `reaction` parameter come from, since I have not assigned it anywhere via `.bind()`?
- If the `binding` of *null* is responsible for this, why is the **order** of the parameters not correct? I bind `null, client, Discord` but in my `messageReactionAdd` I have to specify the parameters like this: `client, Discord, reaction` although I rather thought that reaction is the first `parameter`

Can someone explain to me why the order of the `parameters` is inverted and if assigning *null* as `parameter` to an event acts like a placeholder to supply event-specific `parameters`?

*If you need more code please let me know and I'll add it as fast as possible*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what [`Function#bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) actually does.

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

As mentioned here, `bind()` will *pre*pend parameters to the function when it is called, which is how the order ends up how it is. Here's an example:

```js
function test(param1, param2, param3) {
  console.log(param1);
  console.log(param2);
  console.log(param3);
};

// when `boundFunction` is called, `param1` and `param2` will
// be assigned to `1` and `2` respectively
const boundFunction = test.bind(null, 1, 2);

// in this scenario, `3` will actually be `param3`
boundFunction(3);
```

What about the first parameter, which in this example and your code is `null`? The first parameter takes the place of the `this` keyword. [Read more about `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

For example:

```js
// sample function
function test(param) {
  console.log(`This: ${this}`);
  console.log(`Param: ${param}`);
};

// bind the function
const boundFunction = test.bind(1, 2);

// execute it
boundFunction();

// even though `1` is the first argument, it will not
// be passed as `param`, but instead as `this`
// everything after will be passed as parameters
```

So, what exactly is happening in your code? Instead of directly passing a function to the event handler, like this:

```js
client.on('event', () => {
  // this is my handler
});
```

You're creating a *new* function through `bind()` (the first parameter, `null`, isn't actually important. You can set it to something you want if you'd like, but currently it's just in there so you can get to the other parameters). It will prepend `client` and `Discord` to the function, and then any other parameter passed by discord.js will come after. For example:

```js
// for reference, the way to emit events is with
// `client.emit('eventName', paramToBePassed1, param2, ...);`

// if this event is emitted:
client.emit('message', message);

// you should be listening for:
function handleEvent(client, Discord, message) {
  // ...
}


// again:
client.emit('something', age, name);

// you should be listening for:
function handleEvent(client, Discord, age, name) {
  // ...
}
```

The number of parameters, names of parameters, values of parameters, and function implementations don't actually matter in my above examples, I'm just trying to show that everything will go after `client` and `Discord`.

What if you want `client` and `Discord` to go *last*? Unfortunately, there's no handy built-in function like `bind()`, but the great news is, you don't need it. `bind()` is only used out of convenience so you don't have to actually make an array function.

```js
client.on(event_name, event.bind(null, client, Discord));

// is equivalent to:
client.on(event_name, (...args) => event.bind(null, client, Discord)(...args));

// or without assigning `null` to `this`:
client.on(event_name, (...args) => event(client, Discord, ...args));
```

The spread operator (`...`) is used to capture every single argument passed through the event handler, no matter how many or what they are, and distribute them right back into the function call. Here's an example:

```js
// take every argument given
function log(...args) {
  // and give them right back
  console.log(...args);
}

log(1);
log('hamsters', true, [{ foo: 'bar' }]);
```

Now that we've simplified it to `(...args) => event(client, Discord, ...args)`, it's completely in our control to change the order.

```js
// final solution
(...args) => event(...args, client, Discord)
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad I could help!